# Does `helm upgrade` use rolling restarts for `deployments`, yes/no? if not then what is the default?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, helm

I ask because:

- I want to know what is the default `helm upgrade` behavior
- I might need to change the default `helm upgrade` behavior

#### Does `helm upgrade` use rolling restarts for `deployments`? If not then what is the default?

If `helm upgrade` is not the thing that controls the behavior for `deployments`, please say what does. (I suspect the `deployment` controls the behavior of what happens during a `helm upgrade` but I am not sure so I am asking.)

Comment: i don't know enough about `helm upgrade` to say for sure. but in the kubernetes deployments docs it does say there are two choices for a deployment's `.spec.strategy.type`: `Recreate` and `RollingUpdate`. the default if you do not specify the strategy is `RollingUpdate`. p.s. there is no 'rolling restarts'

Comment: the closest thing i found to `rolling restart` was `kubectl rollout restart deployment`. so likely that is what the `rolling restart`.

Answer (score 1):

Helm upgrade is making revisions to the deployment which means, you can roll back to the last deployment.
regarding the restart of current pods, it will happen based on your definition of Deployment.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate will recreate the pods!